# unable to style react-select to bootstrap sm

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-select

I am using react-select multi-select ( https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select ). I am using bootstrap 4 for styling in my project. I want react-select of size sm as in bootstrap. I tried passing below to style prop in react-select.

```
const customStyles = {
  control: () => ({
    height: 'calc(1.5em + .5rem + 2px)',
    padding: '.25rem .5rem',
    fontSize: '.875rem',
    lineHeight: '1.5',
    borderRadius: '.2rem'
  })
}
```

These are styles of form-control-sm class from bootstrap. So basically I want the size of react-select same to that of size="sm" in bootstrap form-control.

Exactly I want https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#select-menu at here *class="custom-select custom-select-sm"*

Answer (score 0):

You can try below style:

```
const customStyles = {
container:  (provided, state) => ({
  ...provided,
  padding: '0',
  border: '0',
  fontSize: '0.65625rem',
}),
control:  (provided, state) => ({
  ...provided,
  height: 'calc(1.5em + 0.5rem + 2px)',
  minHeight: 'calc(1.5em + 0.5rem + 2px)',
  fontSize: '0.65625rem',
  borderColor: '#d8dbe0',
  boxShadow: 'inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075)',
  transition: 'background-color 0.15s ease-in-out, border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out',
  ':hover': {
    borderColor: state.isFocused ? '#66afe9' : '#d8dbe0',
    boxShadow: state.isFocused ? 
      'inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6)' : 
      'inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075)',
  }
}),
valueContainer: (provided, state) => ({
  ...provided,
  marginTop: '0',
  marginLeft: '6px',
  padding: '0',
  border: '0',
}),
dropdownIndicator: (provided, state) => ({
  ...provided,
  marginTop: '0',
  padding: '0',
  border: '0',
  width: '16px',
}),
clearIndicator: (provided, state) => ({
  ...provided,
  marginTop: '0',
  padding: '0',
  border: '0',
  width: '16px',
}),
indicatorsContainer: (provided, state) => ({
  ...provided,
  paddingRight: '4px',
  border: '0',
}),
```

}